# Should I remove inline CSS after full css has downloaded?

Tags: html, css, performance, inline-code

I've been playing around with Filament's Critical CSS (https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunt-criticalcss) and have a question about it's usage.

As I've been using the tool, it generates a "critical" sheet for every page I point it at so that I can inline those files into my HTML via a <style> tag in the <head>. This all makes sense.

However, once the user visits any of my sites pages, they'll have the main sheet fully cached. At this point does it make sense to stop inlining the CSS, as the user already has the CSS loaded, and instead link to it via a traditional  tag?

Comment: You shouldn't default to inline css at all...

Comment: Clarified my question, by inline I was referring to sticking the critical CSS in a <style> tag in the <head>

Comment: I still would not recommend doing this at all. There is not enough of a increase in your ability to load the page in most cases. Images are a much larger concern ... However.. if you want to do either or just do a cookie that only ties to the css and in the head of the html have an `if else` statment that does one or the other if they have the cookie or not.

Comment: Google's Page Insights (developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) would disagree with you. There may not be enough of a performance gain for all websites or apps to make this particular practice worth it; but it does pay dividends for certain apps. I agree that HTTP requests are a much bigger deal though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're certain that the user has the stylesheet cached this would be a valid approach, assuming that parsing a cached stylesheet or inline styling of critical css will take the same amount of time.

You however can't be certain that it exists in the users cache. As the critical css also exists in the stylesheet this isn't a problem, but it will make rendering the page slower.

The only way to know when it might be useful is to parse your access logs, try to find how often the stylesheet is also requested when a specific page is requested by a specific user. Using that you can create a probabilistic model on when it's useful to inline critical css. This seems like too much work for a small gain. I'm guessing that using inline critical css is most useful for landing pages or pages that go viral.

Comment: Well, actually the method I was thinking of is a bit more crude.  When a user visits for the first time, serve critical CSS in the head and ajax full file. Then simply set a "visited" cookie. I'd just make the assumption that if they've visited than they don't need me serve the document with critical CSS in the head. It's an assumption, but downloading inline CSS when the user has the full file seems like a waste to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Inline CSS usually now is only needed when you want it to take complete precedence over an external style-sheet you do not control of a .JS file that makes unwanted changes which overwrites your style-sheet as well.  Doing this also helps with performance, band-width, etc., etc.

Comment: Actually, inlining "critical" CSS is a page speed (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) recommendation and generally considered a best front-end practice for optimal performance. 

This question has nothing to do with specificity and when I say "inline" I mean in a <style> tag in the <head>

Comment: any <style> in the <head> is called 'Header' styling.  'Inline' styling means it is literally in the same line.  And yes it is a recommendation for performance when it is absolute and needs no outside interference.  This is why inline styling overwrites everything else except !important.

Comment: I was using the term "inline" in the same vein as this article (http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/inline-small-css.html). To me it simply means to stick the CSS in the HTML file (either through style tags or style attributes) I'm referring to "Header" styling as you call it. My question doesn't have anything to do with styling via the style attribute on an element or "Inline" styling as you call it. I'm asking about optimal performance with Critical or Above The Fold CSS practices which are done via a <style> tag in the <head>.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer here as it is best to do so instead of in comments.

The problem that you're having is strange in the matter that you are wanting to cover all possible bases with two separate, but tied issues.

Firstly, your performance gains. Since you want to have higher performance doing inline styles is the technically correct answer. There are some minor gains because you are not doing a request. All requests that go out take time and depending on the time it takes for the server to communicate each request you will see a possible performance drop. This is why some requests that are much larger are considered excessive and Google generally informs you to sprite the image or some other form of connection.

The other part is you want ease of accessibility and want to be able to update quickly which is what would be provided by an actual CSS file. You would need to at some point call this CSS file so that it can be cached into the browser as you expect. You can do some cookie checks and depending if the user has been to the site or not they will have a specific call, but here is the major issue:

At some point you HAVE to actually load it. You will have to make the call. Whether it be on the first load or the last at some point for it to be cached it actually has to be retrieved. You will spend a ton of time checking each variable if they don't have it they will need to have the style sheet loaded. If you are already required to load it at some point then it comes down to never really needing to do inline styles. And if you have inline styles you never really need to load it.

You could potentially do a PHP include of the file and have it pull in that way. You would just include the file between a style declaration and it would populate the CSS that way. I wouldn't say that is the best way to do it, but it is possible. It can be done. I still stand by saying inline is not the right way to go. Technically yes it can help. Reality... no. I have not seen it be beneficial ever in my time. If someone wants to show me one that is fine, but I doubt I will use this practice unless it is last resort.

Keep in mind this final thought. Most cases inline styles are styles that are meant to be final styles; ones that end overwrite original external style sheets that we as developers can not edit ourselves (or do not want to change for other reasons).

Google is great and they provide great research, but research is meant to be considered and not always used exactly as they write. It is to provide insight. Not usually a guide into the way.

Comment: Appreciate your insights, thanks for writing. I view critical css as not only an actual performance gain, but a perceived one as well.  But you're right, in that it only makes sense if you're able to easily cover your bases.